# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error with Connection Manager

Tags: ssis

I am trying to connect to db server from ETL servers through SSIS package. Connection is not working from any ETL servers through SSIS. Below is the screenshot. Please let me know what I am missing.

We also performed a test with the telnet client and test was successful.

[image: Error Screenshot]

> Error Message:Test Connection failed because of an error in
> initializing provider. Client unable to establish connection TCP
> provider. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.

Comment: Earlier Native Client 11.0 has a problem with server strictly enforcing TLS1.2.   Test via  [ODBC Driver 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) or update Native Client 11.0 with [QFE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402).

Answer (score 1):

- Restart all SQL Server services
- Check if SQL Server browser is running and SQL Server is configured
  to allow remote connections.
- Check your SSL and TLS settings from the registery settings. The settings between the client and server should be logical and consistent (i.e. if the server only allows 1.2 and the client only supports 1.0)